# Error when uploading 3mn row dataframe from Spark to BigQuery (using Google Connector)

Tags: google-bigquery, pyspark, google-cloud-platform

After a script in pyspark, I try to save my dataframe into BigQuery using the [google provided connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example). Although it runs smoothly for <1mn rows, it returns an error when running for 3mn rows (although the exact same datastructure).

My code is following the google example (but modified to my project/dataset/dataframe):

```
#[START bigquery export]

# Output Parameters
output_dataset = 'product_recommendation'
output_table = 'spark_ALS_recommendations'

# Get Directory for output
output_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output'.format(bucket)
# Delete content if already existing
output_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(output_directory)
output_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(output_path, True)
# Stage data formatted as newline-delimited JSON in Google Cloud Storage.
partitions = range(RddToSave.getNumPartitions())
output_files = [output_directory + '/part-{:05}'.format(i) for i in partitions]

(RddToSave
 .map(lambda (c, s, p): json.dumps({'customer': c, 'sku_id': s, 'prediction': p}))
 .saveAsTextFile(output_directory))

# Shell out to bq CLI to perform BigQuery import.
subprocess.check_call(
    'bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON '
    '--schema customer:STRING,sku_id:STRING,prediction:FLOAT '
    '{dataset}.{table} {files}'.format(
        **dataset=output_dataset, table=output_table, files=','.join(output_files)**
    ).split())

# Manually clean up the staging_directories, otherwise BigQuery
# files will remain indefinitely.
input_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(input_directory)
input_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(input_path, True)
output_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(output_directory)
output_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(
    output_path, True)

#[END bigquery export]
```

Error is the following:

```
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Populating missing itemInfo on-demand for entry: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000017_9912/
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Populating missing itemInfo on-demand for entry: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000641_10536/
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Populating missing itemInfo on-demand for entry: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000118_10013/
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Supplementing missing matched StorageResourceId: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000017_9912/
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Supplementing missing matched StorageResourceId: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000641_10536/
16/08/18 18:09:29 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage: Supplementing missing matched StorageResourceId: gs://dataproc-3a3edead-12ce-4609-ab1f-ca57b20e4da9-us/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201608181808_0543_m_000118_10013/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/5b991dda-2b91-46e9-b21e-12ebfd8f5363/product_recommendation_mllib_v2.py", line 308, in <module>
    dataset=output_dataset, table=output_table, files=','.join(output_files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
16/08/18 18:09:49 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/08/18 18:09:49 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
Job output is complete
```

Given it smoothly worked before, I'm not sure if I should abandon this upload to BigQuery (and find a workaround) or if this is an error I can solve.
wdyt?

Comment: Trial & error shows me anything above 1mn lines failes. Is there a workaround? BigQuery should be able to handle 1mn lines of input right?

Answer (score 1):

All, found the answer: while uploading to BigQuery I can't keep the repartitions in my rdd: i.e. it was set as 80 partitions, I need to bring it back to 1 and it fully works.

Guess that with >1 partitions, the code call multiple parallel command lines to BigQuery at the exact same time thus resulting in a error (tbd)